# Why when switching fragments, recyclerview is lost?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Hello I am newbie in java programming(android). Currently I learn recyclerview use volley in fragments and need help. why when switching fragment one to fragment two and when back to fragment one, recycleview lost? even though at the beginning recyleview available? thanks for help

this is backgroundtask.java

```
Context mContext;
ArrayList<List> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String json_url = "http://192.168.43.215/belajar/contact_mad.php";
private static final String TAG = "BackgroundTask";

public BackgroundTask(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

}

public ArrayList<List> getList()
{
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    int count = 0;
                    while (count<response.length())
                    {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                            List list = new List(jsonObject.getString("Id"),jsonObject.getString("ImageUrl"),jsonObject.getString("Name"));
                            mArrayList.add(list);
                            count++;

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Errorr.............",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    );

    MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQue(jsonArrayRequest);
    Log.e(TAG, "Log Dari background");


    return mArrayList;
}
```

this is recycleradapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<List> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerAdapter";

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<List> arrayList){

    this.mArrayList = arrayList;

}




@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final String name = mTxtName.getText().toString();
    final String email = mTxtEmail.getText().toString();
    final String nameFood = this.mArrayList.get(position).getName();
    final String imageUrl = this.mArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl();

    holder.Name.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getName());
    final Context context = holder.mImageView.getContext();
    Picasso.with(context).load(mArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.mImageView);
    Log.e(TAG, "Log Dari On BindView");


    holder.cvMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityClick.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("imageUrl",imageUrl);
            bundle.putString("name",name);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);*/
            Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView Name;
    RelativeLayout cvMain;
    ImageView mImageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        cvMain = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvMain);

    }
}
```

this is MainMenu.java

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public static TextView mTxtName, mTxtEmail;
private Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mTxtName   = (TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtNavName);
    mTxtEmail   = (TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtNavEmail);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mTxtName.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
    mTxtEmail.setText(bundle.getString("email"));


    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.tempatfragment, new ListMakanan()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.cara_pesan) {

        return true;
    }else if(id == R.id.keluar){
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.list_makanan) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.tempatfragment, new ListMakanan()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.pesan_makanan) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.tempatfragment, new PesanMakanan()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

this is fragment ListMakanan.java

```
public class ListMakanan extends Fragment {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
ArrayList<List> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String TAG = "ListMakanan";


public ListMakanan() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list__makanan, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclervView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getActivity());
    mArrayList = backgroundTask.getList();
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mArrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    Log.e(TAG, "Log Dari View Created");


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use replace on your FragmentManager to switch fragments you are doing a remove(remove any fragments from container) followed by an add(the new fragment).  This wipes out the state of the previous fragment and forces a refresh when you go back, to avoid this you can just call add fragment instead of replace.

Comment: Is it like this `transaction.add(R.id.tempatfragment, new ListMakanan()).addToBackStack(null).commit();` sir?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.

Comment: but in process fragment 1 and 2 be duplicate. sir? and what should use async task in background task or fragment ?